# Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $U=17\mathbb{Z}$, two rings. Suppose $U \subseteq V \subseteq R$, and $V$ is a ring. Prove that $V=U$ or $V=R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $R$ is the ring of integers, let $U$ be the ideal consisting of all multiples of $17.$ Prove that if $V$ is an ideal of $R$ and $U\subset V\subset R$ then either $V = R$ or $V = U.$

I tried, solving this problem as follows:

First of all, it's given $R$ is the ring of integers. We assume the operations defined on $R$ are the usual addition and multiplication of integers.

If $V=U$ then we are done. If $V\neq U$ then, $\exists $ an $a\in V$ such that $17$ does not divide $a$ i.e $(a,17)=1.$

I tried  to solve  this by using the contrapositive , by contradiction but hit a wall evrytime. My heart says to use $\pmod 17$, well ordering axiom, division algoring and so on ....

Staring at this problem for a while now any hints would be greatly appreciated.

**Remark:**
I am taking a weird class of abstract were we start out with rings have not even hear about ideals here is for myself.

**Definition of a Two-Sided Ideal:**

A subring $A$ of a ring $R$ is called a (two-sided) ideal of R if $\forall r \in R$ and $\forall a \in A$ both ra and ar are in $A.$

**Ideal Test:**

- $\hspace{2mm}$  $a-b \in A$ whenever $a,b\in A$ whenever $a,b \in A$
- $\hspace{2mm}$ $ra$ and $ar$ are in A whenever $a\in A $ and $r \in R$

Comment: 17 is prime. 'nuff said.

Comment: $U$ is actually an ideal of $R$. Look at $V/U\subset R/U$.

Comment: not sure 'nuff is said. I agree that  prime is a big part of  this problem

Comment: $R$ is a *cyclic ring-any subring $V$ of $R$ necessarily has a cyclic subgroup of $R = \Bbb Z$ as its additive group. Any such subgroup is of the form $n\Bbb Z$ for some non-negative integer $n$. For any two such subgroups $m\Bbb Z \subset n\Bbb Z \iff n|m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$17\mathbb{Z}$ is prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ and since $\mathbb{Z}$ is principle ideal domain, which kind of ideal is $17\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: maximal?  just googled "prime ideal " and "pid ."My teacher only talk about ufd , pid ... for like 10 minutes since semester started. from wiki   " I is a maximal ideal of a ring R if there are no other ideals contained between I and R."

Comment: So there is no ideal beween $\mathbb{Z}$ and $17 \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yes. And that fact is enough for answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Since $V$ is a subring of $\mathbb Z$ it is also an ideal of $\mathbb Z$ (why?), so $V=n\mathbb Z$ for some integer $n$. From $17\mathbb Z\subseteq V$ you get $n\mid 17$. Now you can finish the proof.

Comment: $$ n|17 = \exits k \in \mathbb{Z}: \frac{17}{n}=k  \Rightarrow 17=k*n $$ so n must be 17. $17\mathbb{Z}=V$

Comment: dont understan how i get the other case. showing n is not a multiple of 17. want to say n=1 since v is a ring it has to be closed under addition , ... ultimately $V=Z$